# Cycles Material — A kind of glitter

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

[image]Hi guys,

I'm trying to simulate the metal flakes that you can see [in this helmet](https://youtu.be/9odyY29IkKU?t=23s). It looks close to a metallic paint + flakes, but it definitely is something else.

I found a few materials that come close to it, like [Mike Pan's Car Paint Material](http://blog.mikepan.com/post/137759885931/realistic-car-paint-brdf-material), but if you look at the video it seems to only show up when it's in the specular and there's a bit of iridescence to it. Also, it completely disappears once it's outside the specular glow.

Do you guys have any idea how to approach this? Any idea of a material that's a bit closer to it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.blendernation.com/2012/03/30/car-paint-shader-with-flakes-for-cycles/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/116870/1322 is one simple solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve a similar result with a `Voronoi` texture controlling the rotation of an [`Anisotropic`](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-anisotropic-shading) shader:
[image: Nodes]

Which gives the following result:
[image: Result]

You can change the color of the material to whatever you want. To make the glitter smaller, increase the `Scale` of the texture. Make sure to play around with the other settings, too! :)

Comment: That's really cool!  You can use the texture to drive a color mix as well to get the different colored flakes.

Answer (score 11):

Ah, what the heck.  This is really just a minor refinement of @R.M's idea.  The color ramp is to control the relative amount of red/yellow flakes.

[image: sparkle material]

Comment: Nice! I think this is as close to the reference image as you can get without writing a custom shader :)