# How can I make a material emulate this stardust lighting effect on mercedes cars?

Tags: materials

So, as the title says, I'm trying to create a material that looks like this (the emissive part):

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: maybe use a glitter texture and give it some emission? Glitter textures: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45358/107598 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/99251/107598

Comment: are you talking about the red lights?

Comment: yeah the red lit part only